# Adding midair glide to character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So here's my issue: trying to get a character to glide as long as I'm holding down the jump button when not touching the ground.

I've tried adding a force and setting the velocity directly. Right now I think the path forward is setting the velocity, but it keeps resetting to zero before I can adjust my glide.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float climb = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    //Are we on the ground?
    _grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, _groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
    //Make sure we are facing the correct direction
    if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
        Flip();
    else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
        Flip();
    _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(CalculateXSpeed(), CalculateYSpeed());
    //Anaimtion stat
    _animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", _grounded);
    _animator.SetFloat("MoveSpeed", Mathf.Abs(move));
    _animator.SetFloat("VerticalVelocity", _rigidbody.velocity.y);
}
/// <summary>
/// Calculate All the force for the final character movement
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
float CalculateXSpeed()
{
    float result;
    if (!_grounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        if (facingRight)
            result = flightPower;
        else
            result = -flightPower;
    }
    else
    {
        result = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MaxSpeed;
    }
    return result;
}
/// <summary>
/// Calculate All the force for the final character movement
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
float CalculateYSpeed()
{
    float result = _rigidbody.velocity.y;
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        if (_grounded)
        {
            result += jumpPower;
            _grounded = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Flight power and max speed are set in the inspector, 5 and 10 respectively.

Comment: You could simply decrease the gravity scale when not grounded and holding jump

Comment: At the moment, im not concerned about the gravity, its trying to get movement on the x-axis

Comment: What do you mean by glide then ? If you're able to move on the ground, do the same in air ?

Comment: think Spyro or rouge and Knuckles from the sonic series. Effectively  Move in the x-axis while slowing falling to the ground

Comment: Then it's exactly what I said... You keep using Inputs for horizontal control, and decrease the gravity scale of your rigidbody so it falls slower

Comment: @Kaitou3d see [the Unity documentation for `Rigidbody2D.gravityScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html) -- In 2D physics, the gravity is a global setting in the Physics2D class but you can also control the proportion of that gravity applied to each object individually using gravityScale. **For example, it may be easier to implement a flying character by turning off its gravity rather than simulating the forces that keep it aloft.**